# Why does OpenAPIClientAxios initialiation fails on loading openapi.json?

Tags: http, flask, axios, cors, openapi

I have a Connexion server running which exposes its api on http://localhost:8090/openapi.json

```
app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir='./swagger/', debug=True)
app.json_provider_class = encoder.JSONEncoder
app.add_api('swagger.yaml', arguments={'title': 'my server API'}, pythonic_params=True)
CORS(app.app)
logging.getLogger('flask_cors').level = logging.DEBUG
app.run(port=8090)
```

The request via firefox returns the response as expected. Running a swagger ui server `openapi swagger-ui http://127.0.0.1:8090/openapi.json` works as expected.

But I have problems to init a node js client.

```
 const api = new OpenAPIClientAxios({definition: 'http://localhost:8090/openapi.json'})
 const client = await api.init<Client>()
```

I receive the following error: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8090/openapi.json. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200

There is a response made, but my flask server does not notice the GET request on the api specification. Where does the response come from? Why is my server not called?

Comment: I added `withCredentials: true` to the axios configuration. Now, the flask server logs the request and adds `Access-Control-Allow-Origin : http://localhost:3000`  to the response header. But I still get the Cross-Origin Request Blocked error. The client runs on port 3000

Comment: Furthermore, I added `CORS(app.app, supports_credentials=True)` to my server. Now it works. But why?